# Request REST service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently at beginner level at javascript and angular.js framework.
My problem is that I cannot make `ngResource` working .

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/432aE3?p=preview)

My code:

JS:

```
var geolocationControllers = angular.module('geolocationControllers', ['ngResource']);

geolocationControllers.controller('geolocationControllers', ['$scope', '$resource',
  function($scope, $resource) {

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
          $scope.position = $resource('http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json', {}, {
            query: {
              method: 'GET',
              params: {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lon: position.coords.longitude
              }
            }
          });
          console.log($scope.position);
        });
      });
    }
  }
]);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="geolocationControllers">
    <label for="location">Your location:</label>
    <input type="text" id="location" size="120" ng-model="position"/>
</div>
```

This outputs to console and is also in input element:

```
function Resource(value) {          shallowClearAndCopy(value || {}, this);        }
```

Comment: Would you mind providing a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/) of what you currently have?

Comment: I finally found some time and added plunker :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this... This will work, I tested it in my browser... you will have to rename the parts you need to...

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>untitled</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myController">

    <label for="location">Your location:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="location" size="120" ng-model="positionText"/>

</body>
</html>
```

**And Javascript**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myController', function ($scope, $http) {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (curPosition) {
            var curLongi = curPosition.coords.longitude;
            var curLati = curPosition.coords.latitude;

            $http.get('http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat='+curLati.toString()+'&lon='+curLongi.toString()).success(function (data) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                    $scope.positionText = data.display_name;
            });


        });
    } 
});
```

Comment: Definitely working thanks. Just for curiosity reasons don't you know why my solution is not working? Because I would like to use ngResource in many cases and maybe it simplifies code? Or why was ngResource created?

Comment: My knowledge about ngResource is from reading some StackOverflow posts... So what I know is that ngResource is a RESTful Factory, that also uses the $http provider that I have shown you, but with additional RESTful functions, to make it easier to interact with. If I understood it right ngRessource is for managing local Datapersistence, while $http is for "normal" POST / GET requests to another webservice. So both are REST providers making a webrequest via AJAX on a background thread...